# C++ CRTP with parametized base class?

Tags: c++, templates, crtp

I am trying to use CRTP with a small variation.  I have one derived class template and wish to apply this to multiple base classes.  But this is either impossible or I just can't get the syntax right.  The following code does not compile but hopefully illustrates what I want to achieve:

```
template <class Derived> struct BaseCats { /* ... */ };
template <class Derived> struct BaseDogs { /* ... */ };
// ....
template <class Derived> struct BaseN { /* ... */ };

template <template <class> class Base>
struct Wrapper 
    : 
    Base<Wrapper> // compile error - Wrapper is not a complete type
{
    Wrapper(int n) 
    { 
       // I do not want to rewrite or forward this 
       // constructor or Wrapper's operators
    }
};

typedef Wrapper<BaseCats> Cats;
typedef Wrapper<BaseDogs> Dogs;
// ...
typedef Wrapper<BaseN> MyTypeN;
```

Can this be done?

**Edit:**

What am I trying to achieve here?

I renamed some of the code above to use a "dogs and cats" metaphor.  There might exists functions such as:

```
void BaseCats<Derived>::print() const 
{ 
    std::cout << (static_cast<const Derived *>this)->n << " cats\n"; 
}
```

But `Wrapper` would contain constructors and operators that are common to both dogs and cats.  Kind of inverted polymorphism where the base class has the specializations.  The reason for doing things this way around is so that constructors and operators do not have to be rewritten or forwarded for each specialization.

Comment: What are you trying to achieve with such design?

Comment: Do you realize that you are trying to make `Base` derive from `Derived` which itself derives from `Base` which itself derives from `Derived`, etc.? You should probably explain what is your goal rather than how you are implementing it, so that we can propose alternatives.

Comment: +1 for an interesting design. Not sure how useful it would be yet

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Your compile error can be solved by this:

```
Base<Wrapper<Base> >
```

You forgot the template arguments.

Comment: Ah yes, I did actually think of that but assumed I'd have to be writing `Base<Wrapper<Base<Wrapper<Base<Wrapper<Base<Wrapper<...> > > > > > > >`

Comment: @paperjam That won't happen as long as the base doesn't inherit Wrapper.